# Regular expression for a line matching to (country name)(tab or space)(visa type)(tab or space)(valid date in any format)

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression pattern in java that will match the following line.

*(`country name`)(`tab or space)`(`visa type`)(`tab or space`)(`valid date in any format`)*

e.g.:

```
United states H1-B 01/01/2020<br/>
Australia L1 2020/01/01
```

I have tried using patterns like following.

```
"(.*)(\\t)(.*)(\\t)(.*)(\\t)(\\z)"
"(\\w*)(\\t)(.*)(\\t)(.*)(\\t)"
```

But none of them are matching to my string. How to do it? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just split around tabs or spaces like this:

```
String input = "United states H1-B 01/01/2020";
String []tokens = input.split("\\s");
```

<del>Then you can access each individual element in the array by index.</del>

Since you know that the last two tokens will be the date and visa type, then you can make sure that the rest of the array represent the country name.

**NOTE:** Of course this assumes the visa type and date value cannot contain any kind of spaces.

Comment: This will capture `United` in one token and `states` in another one.

Comment: @M42 I modified my answer a bit.

Comment: Yes yes... thank you. This is lot easier than regular expression. thanks for the answer.

Comment: @GoodBoy If this solves your problem then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the regular expression:

```
([A-Za-z]+( \b[A-Za-z]+)*)([\t ]+)(.*)([\t ]+)(.*)
```

e.g.:

```
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile("([A-Za-z]+( \\b[A-Za-z]+)*)([\\t ]+)(.*)([\\t ]+)(.*)");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "United states H1-B 01/01/2020\nAustralia L1 2020/01/01";
    System.out.println(
        REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input).replaceAll(
                      "Country: $1, VisaType: $4, Date: $6")
    );
}
```

Output:

```
Country: United states, VisaType: H1-B, Date: 01/01/2020
Country: Australia, VisaType: L1, Date: 2020/01/01
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, Your answer helped me in some different similar situations. It was really helpful. Thank you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the visa type cannot contain whitespace, you might try:

```
"(.*)\\s+([^\\s]+)\s+(\\d+/\\d+/\\d+)"
```

Depending on the date formats that you want to support, you maybe need to change the last matching group accordingly.